# flutter firestore query index not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

im using flutter and firebase firestore currently working on a function. From the documentation I need to create an Index to get my function working, but it doesnt work actually.

my function:

```
getList(String category, ProviderNotifier providerNotifier) async {
List<Data> _myList = [];

DateTime _now = DateTime.now();
DateTime _start = DateTime(_now.year, _now.month-1, 1, 0, 0);

  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await db
  .collection('data')
  .where('category', isEqualTo: category)
  .where('dateWhenProofed', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _start)
  .orderBy('likes', descending: true)
  .limit(3)
  .get();

  snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
    Data data = Data.fromJson(document.data());
    _myList.add(data);
  });

  providerNotifier.myList = _myList;
}
```

I made two indexes, one with likes and one without likes.
**if I remove the orderBy likes in my query, it works perfectly fine. I don't understand it.**

[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: What does firebase return to you? Have you printed it?

Comment: If I leave the order by likes path it says I have to create an index with a link where it automatically creates it for me. If I add the order by Likes line I’m getting no informations from the console, no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is generating an error.  I suggest taking time to find and read that error, because it's telling you what's wrong.

Firestore does not allow you to order primarily on a field other than the one that you used in a range filter.  Your range filter is on "dateWhenProofed", so you must order by that field first.

I suggest reviewing the [documentation on the limitations for ordering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations):

> If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field.

Comment: Hello Doug, thank you for your answer and documentation reference. Im finally able to read the error by adding .catchError((error) => print("---- Failed to: $error")); I didnt find a workable solution for my filter yet. Do you have an idea how to filter: All data of type "data" matching filter "category" in timerange of "timerange" ordered by "likes" ?

Comment: You can reorder query results on the client app after the query completes.

Comment: You mean doing it like this? (The snapshot result): snapshot.docs.sort((a, b) => a['likes'].compareTo(b['likes']));

Comment: Sure, whatever you need to do.

Comment: Thanks alot for your approaches. How about the performance? Do you have any  experience on that?

Comment: You can benchmark the performance of your own code.  That's not something we can do for you.